How do you seed a nested object in EF Core (in .NET 8)?
How do you seed a nested object in EF Core (with .NET 8)?
When I run Add-Migration alpha, I get the following error:
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The seed entity for entity type 'Business' cannot 
be added because it has the navigation 'HeadquartersAddress' set. To seed relationships,  add the entity seed 
to 'Business' and specify the foreign key values {'HeadquartersAddressId'}... 

Here's a simplified example of the seeding I'm attempting:
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);        

        builder.Entity<Business>().HasData(
            new Business { 
                Id=1,
                Name="Company A", 
                HeadquartersAddress=new Address {Id =1, StreetAddress="30000 Market St."},
                               },

                OfficeLocations = [
                    new OfficeLocation {Id = 1, 
                                        Name ="Pine Center",
                                        Address = new Address {Id=2, StreetAddress = "1 Broad St."} 
                                         }] }
            );

    }

and here are the class definitions:
    public class Business
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public List<OfficeLocation>? OfficeLocations { get; set; }
        public Address? HeadquartersAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class OfficeLocation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Address? Address { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

I would prefer not to have to seed each address individually (as an example) - and then have to reference another object that it belongs to.
Also, when I use DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging as suggested, the error changes to the following:
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The seed entity for entity
type 'Business' with the key value 'Id:1' cannot be added because it has the 
navigation 'HeadquartersAddress' set. To seed relationships, add the entity seed to 
'Business' and specify the foreign key values {'HeadquartersAddressId'}.' was thrown 
while attempting to create an instance. 


The error message is very explicit and even tells you what to do. Can you explain what it is you don't understand about it? I'm not sure how useful an answer would be, if it is just paraphrasing the "answer" you already got from the error message.

Do not assign navigation properties during seeding.  Exception is clear, seed entities separately.

It sounds like I have to seed the Address separately via builder.Entity<Business>().HasData() and add the property "HeadquartersAddressId" to the Business class. And  that fixes that error.  And to fix the next error, I have to seed the OfficeLocation separately and add the property BusinessId to it.

And then everything works.
The language "the navigation 'HeadquartersAddress' set" wasn't clear.

When you seed, autogeneration of primary keys is disabled. You have to explicitly specify them, like this:
builder.Entity<Business>().HasData(
   new Business { 
      Id=1,
      Name="Company A", 
      HeadquartersAddress=new Address {Id = 1, StreetAddress="30000 Market St."},
      },

      OfficeLocations = [
         new OfficeLocation {Id = 1, 
            Name ="Pine Center",
            Address = new Address { Id = 2, StreetAddress = "1 Broad St."} 
      }] }
   );


I made that change (and updated the question), but I'm still getting the same error.

can you create a project on github - I would like to look
